# Installing Reskit and libRestKit.a is missing (red text)

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I am following the RestKit setup instructions perfectly, but I am getting libRestKit.a in red in the Linked Binary With Libraries.

Install instructions: 
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

I would try to drag the libRestKit.a file to my project, but cannot find it anywhere in the Restkit download?

Anyone run across this issue?

Running Xcode 4.5.2

UPDATE: See comments below.  Now I am getting "File not Found" for #import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is *NOT* to copy the "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" from any webpage. Type it out as Xcode didn't like the " copied and pasted. I just replaced the " copied and pasted with manually typed and it worked.

Comment: for me the solution was not actually copying the quotes. I just left them out and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install RestKit using CocoaPods, then you include like this: #import "RestKit/RestKit.h"

check how to work with cocoapods and restkit here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13762665/1848750

Answer (score 0):

If your getting the "File not found" error, check your project settings.

- File > Project settings
- Derived Data Location > "Project-relative"
- Select "Advanced"
- Select "Unique"
- Clean & Build

Answer (score -1):

The ".a" file doesn't exist until it's built.  And if you followed those directions perfectly, I'm guessing you have embedded the RestKit project within your own project, yes?

Here is a image from the instructions; a critical step you need to do (provided you have properly added the RestKit.xcodeproj into your own project).  You need to add the .a file (which doesn't exist yet, but will once it's built) as a target dependency to your own app.

[image: make sure to add this as a target dependency]

Comment: Yes, that is in the instructions which I did. When you do that step you get the red text libRestKit.a.  So I downloaded restkit ran there sample project and copied the libRestKit.a file from the derivedData file to where it should be for my app. Now the red text is gone. But now I get "File not Found" for #import <RestKit/Restkit.h>

Comment: Try "`#import "RestKit/RestKit.h"`" or "`#import "RestKit.h"`" and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, that's because you need to add in the **Header Search Paths** from the directions you pointed to. Make sure to include the quotes in there, too.

Comment: Yeah, I did. That is why I said I followed the directions exactly.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, and all you did was simply restate the instructions.